# Matrices: can I cancel terms from either side not using transpose?

Tags: matrices

so I have the equation:

$a^T*x*b = l^T * b$

b is not an N×N matrix (it's 4×1) and thus doesn't have an inverse but is it still correct to assume that this implies:

$a^T*x=l^T$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, what if $b$ is zero?

(unless you mean that the equation holds for all $b$, in which case, yes)

Comment: so if i define for all b (which i have in my working) does this make sense? @DavidLui